# Protractor select values from drop down with promise

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I'm running a protractor tests and filling in a form with dropdowns. How can I ensure that each dropdown has a promise that is resolved before moving onto the next one? Right now I'm using sleeps and know that can't be the right way.

```
  Describe('Filling site utility form', function() {
      beforeEach(function(){
        var input_monthly = by.linkText('Input Monthly');

        browser.wait(function() {
          return browser.isElementPresent(input_monthly);
        });

        var field1 = element(by.id('field1'));
        Test.dropdown(field1, 1);

        var field2 = element(by.id('field2'));
        Test.dropdown(field2, 1);
   });
```

My dropdown function is:

```
 dropdown = function(element, index, milliseconds) {
    element.findElements(by.tagName('option'))
      .then(function(options) {
        options[index].click();
      });
    if (typeof milliseconds !== 'undefined') {
      browser.sleep(milliseconds);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure what you mean but I suspect what you're interested in is this:

```
describe('Filling site utility form', function() {
  beforeEach(function(){
    var input_monthly = by.linkText('Input Monthly');

    browser.wait(function() {
      return browser.isElementPresent(input_monthly);
    });

    var promise1 = element(by.id('field1')).all(by.tagName('option')).get(1).click();
    var promise2 = element(by.id('field2')).all(by.tagName('option')).get(1).click();

    protractor.promise.all([promise1, promise2]).then(function() {
      //what do you want to do next?
    });
  });
});
```